# Older versions?

Tags: upgrade

I'm currently running 5.27 and need to upgrade. I tried upgrading to the latest version and it got stuck. This usually means I need to do smaller upgrade jumps instead of going straight to the latest version. However, the link that used to be on the download page to older versions is gone. And the release announcements all point to the download page.

What would be the link(s) I need to go to 5.28, 5.29, and 5.30? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manipulate the download link

https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.30.0-drupal.tar.gz

https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.28.4-drupal.tar.gz

https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.29.0-drupal.tar.gz

or you can use [sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/) to get all versions.

Comment: Yes, thank you! That's the link that used to be on the download page, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar position and spotted the urls follow a similar pattern and just changed the version numbers...

https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.31.1-wordpress.zip

https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.30.0-wordpress.zip

https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.29.0-wordpress.zip

https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-5.28.0-wordpress.zip